# php Allow only numeric data and comma, remove duplicate comma

Tags: php, preg-replace, replace

I have a script I am working on for an automated task, so I am not really worried about clean code as it will be used only one time anyways.

The script reads off of a flat file and stores the information into an array which will later be used to read something out of a database.

However, I only want numeric data, so I used preg_replace() and a comma. My code is as follows.

These are read from values in the flat file using a loop.

```
$store = array();
$store[] = 111;
$store[] = 2;
$store[] = 4;
$store[] = 55;
$store[] = 66;
$store[] = 'Kilory';
$store[] = 9090;

$theList[$i] = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]/u', '', implode( ',', $store ) );
unset( $store );
```

the result that this gives me is 0,2,4,55,66,,9090. If I was to try and use the information for use in a mysql IN() statement, it would spit an error back at me due to having two commas next to each other. What is the best way to remove duplicates next to each other?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

duplicate comma including heading and trailing commas you can remove with `$string = trim(preg_replace('#,{2,}#', ',', $string), ',');`.

Comment: ...and if there are 3 commas?

Comment: He did say recursively. If you have three commas and you use his function, you'll be left with two...which will turn into one on the next pass.

Comment: fixed, sorry. (But he talked only about double, not triple)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld no: recursively is wrong, I just tested it myself (= my error). I've changed it to preg_replace.

Comment: @bwoebi +1 Works for multiple commas now :)

Comment: `while (strpos($str,",,") !== false) $str = str_replace(",,",",",$str);` works and is far, far lighter than regular expressions provided that your user does not decide to give you 25 commas in one go.

Comment: there won't be any trailing/heading commas with `implode()`.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Yes. But this is slower as a regular expression if there are many commas.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson added a trim. Now prefect? :o

Comment: @bwoebi: building a benchmark right now to prove you wrong. http://sebrenauld.co.uk/commabenchmark.php and http://sebrenauld.co.uk/commabenchmark2.php. I abused of commas in the second one... Which one is the fastest? 75% faster on double commas, roughly the same with 10 commas lined up on each. Text picked is lipsum on one side, first page of Paradise Lost on the other.

Comment: I meant: When there are a lot of multiple commas (odd number favourably), then preg is faster

Answer (score 1):

PHP offers a filter function for that purpose:

```
$store = array();
$store[] = 111;
$store[] = 2;
$store[] = 4;
$store[] = 55;
$store[] = 66;
$store[] = 'Kilory';
$store[] = 9090;

$theList[$i] = implode(',', array_filter($store, 'is_numeric'));
unset($store);
```

Comment: +1 undoubtedly a better way, but doesn't quite do the same thing with for example decimal points and partially numeric values :)

Comment: You can always replace the 'is_numeric' callback with another one that  better suits the current use case.

Answer (score 0):

when looping through the `store[]` values, use the `is_numeric()` function to check whether the value is numeric. if it is, add the commas, if it isn't, don't.

[manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

Comment: wrong. `is_nan()` checks for `=== NaN`. What you mean is `is_numeric()`.